# Joomla menu select article popup not working

Tags: joomla, menu, popup, article

I am using Joomla! 2.5.24. When I am trying to select article for menu earlier i used to get popup but now neither getting popup nor new window. Is there any other way to select article or how to fix this issues so that i can get popup for article selection.
Any suggestions??
Thanks

Comment: Sounds like a jquery conflict. Please try to inspect your page code to see if there are multiple instances of jquery loading and disable the component / plugin that loads them. Please try also to clear your browser cache, joomla cache and joomla sessions table.

Comment: Nice to hear that, you are welcome!